# jquery 1.4.1 breaks my slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-1.4

After toying with the jquery slideshow extension, I created my own that better suited my purposes ( I didn't like that all the images needed to load at the beginning for instance).  Now, upon upgrading to jQuery 1.4.2 (I know I'm late), the slideshow loads the first image fine ( from the line`$('div#slideshow img#ssone').fadeIn(1500);` towards the bottom), but doesn't do anything beyond that. Does anyone have any idea which jquery construct is killing my script?  The live page is at [lplonline.org](http://lplonline.org) which is using 1.3.2 for the time being. Thanks in advance.

```
Array.prototype.random = function( r ) {
var i = 0, l = this.length;
 if( !r ) { r = this.length; }
 else if( r > 0 ) { r = r % l; }
 else { i = r; r = l + r % l; }
 return this[ Math.floor( r * Math.random() - i ) ];
};

jQuery(function($){
    var imgArr = new Array();
    imgArr[1] = "wp-content/uploads/rotator/Brbrshop4-hrmnywkshp72006.jpg";
    imgArr[2] = "wp-content/uploads/rotator/IMGA0125.JPG";
    //etc, etc, about 30 of these are created dynamically from a db

var randImgs = function () {

    var randImg = imgArr.random();
        var img1 = $('div#slideshow img#ssone');
        var img2 = $('div#slideshow img#sstwo');

        if(img1.is(':visible') ) { 
            img2.fadeIn(1500);
            img1.fadeOut(1500,function() {
                img1.attr({src : randImg});
            });


        } else {
            img1.fadeIn(1500);
            img2.fadeOut(1500,function() {
                img2.attr({src : randImg});
            });

        }
}

setInterval(randImgs,9000); //  9 SECONDS

$('div#slideshow img#ssone').fadeIn(1500);

});
</script>

<div id="slideshow">
<img id="ssone" style="display:none;" src="wp-content/uploads/rotator/quote-investments.png" alt="" />
<img id="sstwo" style="display:none;" src="wp-content/uploads/rotator/quote-drugs.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  I've inherited this website, and it seems that the original creator of the site called about 3 or 4 different js libraries (scriptalicious, prototype...) in the header.  None of them were actually being used though.  I took all of that cruft out, and now it works beautifully, so the problem was somehow in the interaction between jQuery and one of the other libraries.  Thank you Dan Heberden for your time and advice in any case!

Answer (score 2):

It's because how your function is scoped - assign it a variable like this:

```
var randImgs = function() {
  // do stuff
}
```

now your setInterval has a reference to the correct function.

As a quick note: div#slideshow (or any tag/id combo) is un-efficient. The ID is meant ONLY for that element so saying "look at all the divs and find the id of.." is unnecessary.

Use that approach, however, with classes such as div.myClassName - to say 'look at all the divs and find the class..'.

Same goes with parent/child - #parent #child - is extra work - #child can be found by itself. #parent div.myClassName however would be sensible, as that helps narrow the search for the divs with classname of myClassname.

Comment: 1) Could you explain why I can't make a function and then call it like I did? (I'm more familiar with php, so maybe there's some different here...)


2) Again, interesting thought on not using the element#id, but instead using just #id.  In css, it's better to use div#id because it limits what needs to be searched for that id.  Is javascript (or jQuery) different?


3) Lastly, I made the scope change you suggested, but that did not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: it's because setInterval is run NOT in the scope of that anonymous function. The call 'to' setInterval is, but not the resulting interval. When you send it a reference (variable = function) then it holds the link. 2) my tip was for both jQuery and css - (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS). there is no need to 'search' for an id - there's only one 3) i'll do another test

Comment: Well perhaps i'm wrong regarding the function reference, because it works with 1.4.2 on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kPG9Z/